# Android SQLite getContact issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hey guys I've done this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

And found it really useful but he doesn't go over how to use the 'db.getContact()'.

Here is the code in the handler for calling it:

```
// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}
```

and I'm attemping to call it by:

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

            String name = db.getContact(id);
            //do something

            }
        }           
    });
```

What is the right syntax for calling and returning what I need, I've tried a lot of different ways but don't understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Contact cn = db.getContact(id);
```